# How to persistently apply iptables rule?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

After much trials and tribulations I have set up a raspberry pi VPN using this (https://sys.jonaharagon.com/2016/05/12/setting-up-an-openvpn-server-on-a-raspberry-pi-2-part-12/) guide. However at the end of part two, the author mentions that the following rule may need to be run on the server in order to access the outside internet:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I have found that unless I run that command I cannot access the outside internet once I am connected to my vpn. Is there an easy way to make this rule apply always?

I have done some searching and came across the following for making iptables rules persistent using iptables-persisten. However I was hesitant to continue installing more packages I did not understand the purpose of, possibly screw up my existing configuration, and I wanted to ensure this was the only/most legitimate way to make this rule "stick" across reboots of the Pi.

EDIT: I am using rasbian, Jessie, on my pi

Comment: it would worth to mention a Linux distribution you are using with your RPi

Comment: Rasbian, will add to question

Comment: @PseudoNym01 take a look at this page https://wiki.debian.org/iptables this can be done with some packages too.

Comment: it seems for raspbian you should put the ruules into `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` to make them persistent. see here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=604012#p604012